# Repeat a set of elements on user click using knockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following input form:

```
   Contact Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: contactName" />
   Contact Email ID: <input type="text" data-bind="value: contactEmailID" />
   Contact Number: <input type="text" data-bind="value: contactNumber" />
   <a>Add another contact</a>
```

When user clicks on `Add another contact`, I have to repeat the above HTML elements one more time and take user input like this:

```
   Contact Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: contactName" />
   Contact Email ID: <input type="text" data-bind="value: contactEmailID" />
   Contact Number: <input type="text" data-bind="value: contactNumber" />
   <a>Add another contact</a>

   Contact Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: contactName" />
   Contact Email ID: <input type="text" data-bind="value: contactEmailID" />
   Contact Number: <input type="text" data-bind="value: contactNumber" />
   <a>Add another contact</a>
```

The details entered by the user in each repeated section has to be saved in an `observableArray` called `ContactDetails` contatining `contactName`, `contactEmailID` and 
`contactNumber` properties so that we can convert the array to `JSON` and send it to server to be added in the database table.

Also the user can add up to a maximum of 3 contacts. If user has 3 sections to enter contact details, then the `Add another contact` link should be disabled and a remove link should appear for the 2nd and 3rd sections.

How can I acheive all this using knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the foreach binding to bind your observableArray. When you click Add another contact just push and empty details object into ContactDetails and your UI will update.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/raMCN/

```
function myVM() {
    var self = this;
    self.ContactDetails = ko.observableArray();

    self.addContact = function() {
        self.ContactDetails.push(new contactVM());
    };
}

function contactVM() {
    var self = this;
    self.contactName = ko.observable();
    self.contactEmailID = ko.observable();
    self.contactNumber = ko.observable();
}

var vm = new myVM();
var contact = new contactVM();
contact.contactName("foo");
contact.contactEmailID("m@bar.com");
contact.contactNumber("555-1234");
vm.ContactDetails.push(contact);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```